# imageOrientation returns Up, but photo shows up upsidedown

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm grabbing some photos from the iPad photo library. I took a few test photos in landscape mode, both with the iPad home button on the left side, and then the right side.

So in my app, for some reason some of the photos show up upsidedown. I checked their `imageOrientation` property, and they are all 0 (meaning they are `UIImageOrientationUp`). So that means I can't even tell which photos I need to rotate.

What's going on, and how can I tell which photos need to be rotated? Thanks

Comment: see this https://github.com/cosnovae/fixUIImageOrientation

Comment: You can also refer similar post [AVFoundation Image orientation off by 90 degrees in the preview but fine in Camera roll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956750/avfoundation-image-orientation-off-by-90-degrees-in-the-preview-but-fine-in-came/16074603#16074603)

Answer (score 4):

A UIImage has a property imageOrientation, which instructs the UIImageView and other UIImage consumers to rotate the raw image data. There's a good chance that this flag is being saved to the exif data in the uploaded jpeg image, but the program you use to view it is not honoring that flag.

To rotate the UIImage to display properly when uploaded, you can use a category like this:
In .h file

UIImagefixOrientation.h

```
@interface UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation;

@end
```

UIImagefixOrientation.m

```
@implementation UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

   // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
   // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

  switch (self.imageOrientation) {
      case UIImageOrientationDown:
      case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
         transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
          break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
}

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
}

// Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
// calculated above.
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
        break;
}

// And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return img;
}

@end
```

And call this function during capture image save or select image from the gallery.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your function. However, a potential issue is that the upside down files all return UIImageOrientationUp. None of them return anything other than 0, which is problematic.

Comment: can you send me thje code for i will try it from my side .and i solve u r error .

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into your image code, could it be due to the flipped coordinate system on iOS?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html

~snip:

> **Configuring Your View to Use Flipped Coordinates**
>
> The first step you need to take to implement flipped coordinates is to decide the default orientation of your view. If you prefer to use flipped coordinates, there are two ways to configure your view’s coordinate system prior to drawing:
>
> Override your view’s isFlipped method and return YES. Apply a flip
>   transform to your content immediately prior to rendering.

So in your view, you can try adding `-(BOOL)isFlipped` and return `YES` and test if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem. use this function to resolve:

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *) image {
int kMaxResolution = 320;

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);


CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
    }
    else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
    }
}

CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
CGFloat boundHeight;
UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
switch(orient) {

    case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
}
else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
}

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageCopy;
}
```