# AVFoundation Image orientation off by 90 degrees in the preview but fine in Camera roll

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Something really strange is happening, I am trying to capture an image using AVFoundation, the Camera roll image seems just fine, but the image preview has the image rotated by 90 degrees.

This is the code I am using to capture an image

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection)
    {
        break;
    }
}

//NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
     if (exifAttachments)
     {
         // Do something with the attachments.
         //NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"no attachments");
     }

     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];

     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

     self.vImage.image = image;

     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
 }];
```

Comment: Why did the get a vote down by the way? is the solution that trivial? if it is please enlighten me! This is a place to learn not to be shunned. I am trying my best to learn, just like you would've at some point of time!

Comment: Have got this preview thing working right, if yes then pls share this with us

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580115/9440709

Answer (score 51, accepted):

yes ,it happens when you  capture image in Portrait orientation of your device and use that image in your application, because the default orientation of image is Landscape in any IOS Device, so you need to change the orientation of image after picking from Gallery to use in your app.

I have put code to achieve this

**Objective-C code**

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientationOfImage:(UIImage *)image {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, image.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, image.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, image.size.width, image.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.height,image.size.width), image.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height), image.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
```

**Swift code**

```
func fixOrientationOfImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
   if image.imageOrientation == .Up {
      return image
   }

   // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
   // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
   var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

   switch image.imageOrientation {
   case .Down, .DownMirrored:
      transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, image.size.height)
      transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
   case .Left, .LeftMirrored:
      transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0)
      transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
   case .Right, .RightMirrored:
      transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, image.size.height)
      transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -CGFloat(M_PI_2))
   default:
      break
   }

   switch image.imageOrientation {
   case .UpMirrored, .DownMirrored:
      transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0)
      transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
   case .LeftMirrored, .RightMirrored:
      transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.height, 0)
      transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
   default:
      break
   }

   // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
   // calculated above.
   guard let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(image.size.width), Int(image.size.height), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage), 0, CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage), CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage).rawValue) else {
      return nil
   }

   CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform)

   switch image.imageOrientation {
   case .Left, .LeftMirrored, .Right, .RightMirrored:
      CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.height, height: image.size.width), image.CGImage)
   default:
      CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size), image.CGImage)
   }

   // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
   guard let CGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context) else {
      return nil
   }

   return UIImage(CGImage: CGImage)
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
func fixOrientationOfImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    if image.imageOrientation == .up {
        return image
    }

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    switch image.imageOrientation {
       case .down, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: image.size.height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
    case .left, .leftMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.rotated(by:  CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
    case .right, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
        transform = transform.rotated(by:  -CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
    default:
        break
    }

    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.width, y: 0)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
    case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
        transform = transform.translatedBy(x: image.size.height, y: 0)
        transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
    default:
        break
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(image.size.width), height: Int(image.size.height), bitsPerComponent: image.cgImage!.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: image.cgImage!.colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: image.cgImage!.bitmapInfo.rawValue) else {
        return nil
    }

    context.concatenate(transform)

    switch image.imageOrientation {
      case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
        context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.height, height: image.size.width))
       default:
          context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    guard let CGImage = context.makeImage() else {
        return nil
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: CGImage)
}
```

Comment: Dipen, yes I ended up using something similar. but I am facing another problem, I want my saved image to be cropped to the content that I am displaying in my square video container. but thats not the case, its even saving the part of the image that is not visible in the box.

Comment: for that you needs to use some cropping methods to crop image, which are available in QuartzCore framework.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara - GREAT STUFF!!  You are great, Dipen.  I need a little help with the logic here.  I copied it into my project and used it and "voila" my image was rotated.  Yay!  But when execution gets to the redraw section the orientation is not what I need it to be.  I'm trying to understand what is happening at each step here and not getting it yet.  I'll keep researching but would love it if you or someone else could chime in and enlighten me.  Thanks again for such a great post!

Comment: Thank you sir! I've been looking for days for this.. now I've just got to find code that fixes the UIImageView stretching after stillImageOutput has been fired haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: I get Black screen for image

Comment: @LGL there must be something wrong with image instance otherwise it works like a charm. to make any conclusion need to review your code.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara it does my problem was with SDWebImage, that mess up my image

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for images captured by AVCapturePhotoOutput

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.5 +**

you should set the orientation of the output before you capture the image.

```swift
// set the image orientation in output
  if let photoOutputConnection = self.photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
        photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = videoPreviewLayerOrientation!
    }

self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: photoCaptureProcessor) // capture image
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works, but is much more complicated than it needs to be. You can use the following to rotate the image.

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage*)image toRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat (^rad)(CGFloat) = ^CGFloat(CGFloat deg) {
        return deg / 180.0f * (CGFloat) M_PI;
    };

    // determine the orientation of the image and apply a transformation to the crop rectangle to shift it to the correct position
    CGAffineTransform rectTransform;
    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(90)), 0, -image.size.height);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-90)), -image.size.width, 0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad(-180)), -image.size.width, -image.size.height);
            break;
        default:
            rectTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    };

    // adjust the transformation scale based on the image scale
    rectTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(rectTransform, image.scale, image.scale);

    // apply the transformation to the rect to create a new, shifted rect
    CGRect transformedCropSquare = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, rectTransform);
    // use the rect to crop the image
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, transformedCropSquare);
    // create a new UIImage and set the scale and orientation appropriately
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    // memory cleanup
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return result;
}
```

To just rotate the image and not crop, you can simply call it like this:

```
UIImage *image;
[self cropImage:image toRect:rect.bounds];
```

Comment: @decades for which orientation and device does it not work for? Also, keep in mind that this is looking at the image's orientation, so if it is not recorded into the image (which I believe you have to set manually if you build your own around the AV frameworks), this won't work.

Comment: I was trying your code in conjunction with the results from captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection. Maybe I was wrong here

Comment: In the end answer 17 together with my commented change was a perfect solution for my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845520/why-does-avcapturevideoorientation-landscape-modes-result-in-upside-down-still-i

Comment: @decades Is there a way to rotate data obtained by requestImageDataForAsset

Comment: @TejasPadliya in the result handler, you can instantiate a ```UIImage``` from the ```NSData``` object with ```[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]```

Answer (score 1):

Dipen Panchasara's answer is great, but there could be one problem with it. When you process big images (for example from iPhoneX) there will be massive memory peak which can be an issue in some cases.

So, maybe you want to change that line:

```
context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.height, height: image.size.width))
```

for something with some memory optimization. For example, that will break image drawing in 16 (4*4) steps, which decrease memory consumption significantly:

```
let partInAxis: CGFloat = 4
let partWidth = image.size.height/partInAxis
let partHeight = image.size.width/partInAxis
for i in 0...Int(partInAxis)-1 {
   for j in 0...Int(partInAxis)-1 {
      let partialImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(x: CGFloat(i)*partWidth, y: CGFloat(j)*partHeight, width: partWidth, height: partHeight))
      context.draw(partialImage!, in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(i)*partWidth, y: CGFloat(Int(partInAxis)-1-j)*partHeight, width: partWidth, height: partHeight))
   }
}
```

**Be aware, that in this case height and width of image must be divided by 4.**

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Yodagama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580115/3151675), since it's a one-liner and much cleaner. However, if you need to correct the orientation in another way, here's [Dipen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074603/3151675) without forced optionals, as a UIImage extension. For better memory optimization, mix it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54984526/3151675).

```
extension UIImage {
    var fixedOrientation: UIImage? {
        if imageOrientation == .up {
            return self
        }

        // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
        // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        switch imageOrientation {
        case .down, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi)
        case .left, .leftMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
        case .right, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by:  -.pi / 2)
        default: break
        }

        switch imageOrientation {
        case .upMirrored, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        case .leftMirrored, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.height, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        default: break
        }

        guard let cgImage = cgImage,
              let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace else {
            return nil
        }

        // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
        // calculated above.
        let context = CGContext(
            data: nil,
            width: Int(size.width),
            height: Int(size.height),
            bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent,
            bytesPerRow: 0,
            space: colorSpace,
            bitmapInfo: cgImage.bitmapInfo.rawValue
        )

        guard let context = context else {
            return nil
        }

        context.concatenate(transform)

        switch imageOrientation {
          case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
            context.draw(cgImage, in: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.height, height: size.width))
           default:
              context.draw(cgImage, in: .init(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }

        // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
        guard let newCgImage = context.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }

        return .init(cgImage: newCgImage)
    }
}
```