# AVFoundation CaptureStillImage issue with orientation of result image

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have a custom camera view controller that uses AVFoundation to capture a still image which you can see here: [image: Capture Preview]

My issue is that once I capture an image, the orientation is always sideways which you can see here[image: Captured Image]

My code is as follows:

```swift
    var captureInput: AVCaptureInput?
    var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var currentDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    @IBAction func captureButtonTap(sender: UIButton) {
        if(!capturingPhoto){
        capturingPhoto = true
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            self.stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
                if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                    var imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    var image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    var imageWidth = image?.size.width
                    var cropRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth!, height: imageWidth!)
                    var imageRef: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image!.CGImage, cropRect)
                    var croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)!
                    self.imagePreview.image = croppedImage
                    self.image = croppedImage
                    self.switchModeToPreview()
                }
            })
            }
            }
        }
    }

        func initCameraSession(){
        configureDevice()
        NSLog(String(selectedCamera))
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
        if(selectedCamera == 0){
            var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
            currentDevice = backCamera
        }else if(selectedCamera == 1){
            var frontCamera = frontCameraIfAvalible()
            currentDevice = frontCamera
        }
        if(currentDevice == nil){
            NSException(name: "Error", reason: "Device Has No Camera.", userInfo: nil)
        }
        updateButtons()

        var error: NSError?
        var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice, error: &error)

        if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
            captureSession!.addInput(input)
            captureInput = input
            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
                cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                previewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.width + 139)
                if(currentLayer != nil){
                    currentLayer!.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
                currentLayer = previewLayer!
                captureSession!.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }
```

Please be aware I have left some code out on purpose and if you need further information, just request it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580115/9440709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this, I use this to transform the buttons on my view when I rotate the device. This can be used with the image taken. Recall your standard transformation rotation matrices from linear algebra if you have ever taken that class. Basically, just alter this code to rotate the frame of the image you have captured and then make sure you set its frame bounds back to the view's frame in order to have it fit back correctly in the view. This may be more complicated than need be, But I have never had this issue before with images. Keep in mind this is being called due to a rotation change observer that has been registered, which you may not need to use. But this underlying concept is used A LOT

Any time I have rotation issues, I use this.

```
/**************************************************************************
    DEVICE ORIENTATION DID CHANGE
    **************************************************************************/
    func deviceOrientationDidChange() {

        println("DEVICE ORIENTATION DID CHANGE CALLED")

        let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

        //------ IGNORE THESE ORIENTATIONS ------
        if orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceUp || orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceDown || orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown || orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown || self.currentOrientation == orientation {

            println("device orientation does not need to change --- returning...")

            return
        }


        self.currentOrientation = orientation


        //------ APPLY A ROTATION USING THE STANDARD ROTATION TRANSFORMATION MATRIX in R3 ------

        /*

            x       y       z
            ---           ---
        x | cosø    sinø    0 |
        y | -sinø   consø   0 |
        z | 0       0       1 |
            ---           ---

        */

        //----- PERFORM BUTTON AND VIDEO DATA BUFFER ROTATIONS ------

        switch orientation {

        case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:

            println("Device Orientation Portrait")

            if self.usingFrontCamera == true {
            }
            else {

                self.playBackTransformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.degrees0)
                self.switchCaptureSession.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.switchCaptureSession.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.flipCamera.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.flipCamera.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.captureButton.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.captureButton.frame = self.view.bounds
            }

            break

        case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:

            println("Device Orientation LandScapeLeft")

            if self.usingFrontCamera == true {
            }
            else {

                self.playBackTransformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(self.degrees90))
                self.switchCaptureSession.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.switchCaptureSession.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.flipCamera.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.flipCamera.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.captureButton.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.captureButton.frame = self.view.bounds
            }

            break

        case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:

            println("Device Orientation LandscapeRight")

            if self.usingFrontCamera == true {
            }
            else {

                self.playBackTransformation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-self.degrees90)
                self.switchCaptureSession.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.switchCaptureSession.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.flipCamera.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.flipCamera.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.captureButton.transform = self.playBackTransformation!
                self.captureButton.frame = self.view.bounds
            }

            break

        default:

            break
        }
```

Affine Transformation are great for rotations. There may be a function that sets the default image orientation when captured. Check Apple's references.

Comment: Do you happen to know which delegate calls `deviceOrientationDidChange` or is it an `NSNotification`

Comment: it is a notification that I have registered. This is for device orientation changes. The issue seems, or could be due to, the default orientation of the picture that is captured, when it is in fact captured. If you are wanting to have the picture rotate accordingly with the device, then you should do the following.    UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceOrientationDidChange", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil).

Comment: This code should not be copy and pasted blindly, it serves as a concept of what can be applied.