# UIImagePNGRepresentation() rotate my UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

The image comes from `UIImagePickerViewController`:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        print("1: \(image)")
        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
            print("2: \(UIImage(data: data))")
        }
    }
}
```

The result is following:

> 1:  size {3024, 4032} orientation 3 scale 1.000000
>   2: Optional( size {4032, 3024} orientation 0 scale 1.000000)

Why `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` changes orientation of the image? How to prevent from this?

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956750/avfoundation-image-orientation-off-by-90-degrees-in-the-preview-but-fine-in-came/16074603#16074603) which prevents rotation. Code is in objective-c you can use it as is or convert it in swift.

Comment: It is too complicated, for sure there is much simpler way.

Comment: you just have to pass your image to function and it takes care of rest, though i have added swift code as well. check [now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956750/avfoundation-image-orientation-off-by-90-degrees-in-the-preview-but-fine-in-came/16074603#16074603)

Answer (score 0):

In first case your image orientation is `UIImageOrientationRight` (value 3). In second case the orientation is `UIImageOrientationUp` value 0 which is default.

You can fix the orientation issues while converting images to data and vice versa.

Please se this answer
[iOS UIImagePickerController result image orientation after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload/5427890#5427890)

**Update:**
You can change fix its orientation with code in above link. It will not affect the uploading procedure.

If you are not bothered about the data format, you can convert it to JPEG format

```
like if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) {
  print("2: \(UIImage(data: data))")
}
```

Comment: No, I need to send the data to server via AFNetworking. So i MUST send image with correct orientation. Fixing after converting to data doesnt make sense for me.

Comment: Then try using jpeg representation instead of png